# Refactor model method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods

In my controller I use `@invitation.send_email` to call on this model method:

```
def send_email
  create_digest("cycle")
  ...
end

private
  def create_digest(attribute)
    token       = send("#{attribute}_token")
    digest      = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    self.token  = User.new_token         # So this should translate to self.cycle_token
    self.digest = User.digest(token)     # So this should translate to self.cycle_digest
  end
```

It however generates an error referring to the `self.token  = User.new_token` line in the private method:

```
undefined method `token=' for #<Invitation:0x007f1472d233f8>
```

It does not seem to convert `self.token` into `self.cycle_token`. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The original method is below, but I'm trying to refactor this into something more flexible.

```
def create_cycle_digest
  self.cycle_token  = User.new_token
  self.cycle_digest = User.digest(cycle_token)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing completely wrong. You have to do the dynamic call as below:

```
def create_digest(attribute)
   token = self.public_send "#{attribute}_token=", User.new_token
   self.public_send "#{attribute}_digest=", User.digest(token)
end
```

`public_send` is better to use while calling *public* methods instead of using `send`.

Below 2 lines created to local variables `token`, `digest` inside the method, nothing more than that.

```
token = send("#{attribute}_token")
digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
```

Now, when you are doing something like,

```
self.token  = User.new_token
```

You are actually trying to call the setter method `token=` on the object of the class `Invitation`. As you don't have such method defined, you are getting *no such method* exist error.